# LINQ to XML optional element query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, anonymous-types

I'm working with an existing XML document which has a structure (in part) like so:

```
<Group>
    <Entry>
        <Name> Bob </Name>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Name> Larry </Name>
    </Entry>
</Group>
```

I'm using LINQ to XML to query the XDocument to retrieve all these entries as follows:

```
var items = from g in xDocument.Root.Descendants("Group").Elements("Entry")
    select new
    {
        name = (string)g.element("Name").Value,
        id = g.Elements("ID").Count() > 0 ? (string)g.Element("ID").Value : "none"
    };
```

The "ID" elements aren't always there and so my solution to this was the Count() jazz above.  But I'm wondering if someone has a better way to do this.  I'm still getting comfortable with this new stuff and I suspect that there may be a better way to do this than how I'm currently doing it.

Is there a better/more preferred way to do what I want?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) actually has [interesting explicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit.aspx) that do the right thing in this case.

So, you rarely actually need to access the `.Value` property.

This is all you need for your projection:

```
var items =
    from g in xDocument.Root.Descendants("Group").Elements("Entry")
    select new
    {
        name = (string) g.Element("Name"),
        id = (string) g.Element("ID") ?? "none",
    };
```

And if you'd prefer to use the value of `ID` as an integer in your anonymous type:

```
var items =
    from g in xDocument.Root.Descendants("Group").Elements("Entry")
    select new
    {
        name = (string) g.Element("Name"),
        id = (int?) g.Element("ID"),
    };
```

Comment: see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx for Hanselman's take on it

Answer (score 3):

In a similar situation I used an extension method:

```
    public static string OptionalElement(this XElement actionElement, string elementName)
    {
        var element = actionElement.Element(elementName);
        return (element != null) ? element.Value : null;
    }
```

usage:

```
    id = g.OptionalElement("ID") ?? "none"
```

Comment: ValueOrDefault(this XElement actionElement, string elementName, string defaultValue) would be even tidier.

Comment: It's actually totally unnecessary. The explicit string conversion operator already does this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var items = from g in xDocument.Root.Descendants("Group").Elements("Entry")
            let idEl = g.Element("ID")
            select new
            {
                name = (string)g.element("Name").Value,
                id = idEl == null ? "none" : idEl.Value;
            };
```

if this barfs, then `FirstOrDefault()` etc might be useful, else just use an extension method (as already suggested).